# Fill time gaps in Python

Tags: python

Is there a more elegant way to determine exclusive / exhaustive intervals, given endpoints and some points in between?

The tests below describe the scenario in terms of a one-month billing period and several point or interval divisions within that month.  I want to get a list of pairs detailing the individual intervals resulting from the boundaries given.

```
def test_fill_time_gaps(self):
    bill_period = (localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))

    # test fill first gap
    periods = fill_time_gaps(bill_period, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])
    self.assertEqual(periods, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-04')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])

    periods = fill_time_gaps(bill_period, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                                                           (localtz_parse('2018-03-05'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])
    self.assertEqual(periods, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-04')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-05'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])

    # test fill first and last gap
    periods = fill_time_gaps(bill_period, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-15'))])
    self.assertEqual(periods, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-04')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-15')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-15'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])

    # test fill first gap and gap in between
    periods = fill_time_gaps(bill_period, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                                                           (localtz_parse('2018-03-08'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])
    self.assertEqual(periods, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-04')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-05'), localtz_parse('2018-03-08')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-08'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])

    # test fill first gap and gap in between and last gap
    periods = fill_time_gaps(bill_period, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                                                           (localtz_parse('2018-03-08'), localtz_parse('2018-03-15'))])
    self.assertEqual(periods, [(localtz_parse('2018-03-01'), localtz_parse('2018-03-04')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-04'), localtz_parse('2018-03-05')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-05'), localtz_parse('2018-03-08')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-08'), localtz_parse('2018-03-15')),
                               (localtz_parse('2018-03-15'), localtz_parse('2018-03-31'))])
```

And here is my initial attempt:

```
def fill_time_gaps(boundary, periods):
    """
    Given a period boundary, fill in gaps within given periods
    Assuming periods are in seqential order
    :param boundary: period boundry
    :param periods: sequence of periods, should contain at least one period
    :return: sequence of periods with filled gaps
    """
    if not len(periods):
        raise Exception('periods should contain at least one period')

    # works by stepping through the periods and compare the against the way-point
    # to determine if there is a gap
    result = []
    bound_start, bound_end = boundary
    way_point = bound_start

    for period in periods:
        period_start, period_end = period

        if period_start > way_point:
            gap = (way_point, period_start)
            result.append(gap)

        result.append(period)
        way_point = period_end

    # fill the last gap
    if way_point < bound_end:
        result.append((way_point, bound_end))

    return result
```

But this seems a bit "stupid" (sometimes dumb code is good code, but not sure in this case), I am not sure if this is bulletproof too, but it passes my existing tests.

I am eager to know if there is a better way solving it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the fill logic doesn't really depend on the datetime representation, I've chopped this down to the day numbers for ease of comprehension.

- Take the billing endpoints and include the supplied internal period
  dividers.
- Make a set of this to remove duplicates (billing endpoints)
  and sort the resulting "fence posts".
- Step through this sequence and build periods from adjacent days.
- Return that list to the caller.

Code:

```
def fill_time_gaps(boundary, periods):
    bound = sorted(list(set(boundary + periods)))
    return tuple([(post, bound[i+1]) for i, post in enumerate(bound[:-1])])

billing = (1, 31)
test = [(2, 3),
        (1, 8),
        (10, 31),
        (4, 5, 12)]

for case in test:
    print(fill_time_gaps(billing, case))
```

Output:

```
((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 31))
((1, 8), (8, 31))
((1, 10), (10, 31))
((1, 4), (4, 5), (5, 12), (12, 31))
```

Comment: For your last case `(4, 5, 12)`, the periods are always come in (start, end) tuples, does your function work in this case `(4, 5), (5, 12)`

Comment: No, because I'm showing only the critical logic.  Handling tuple input is a single-step processing detail to flatten any input tuples into their constituent boundaries.  That part can be done on either end.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input, I will give it a bit of time to see if there are any more answers.